# How to get a link of the video I uploaded to YouTube

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, youtube, youtube-api

My code can upload the video to YouTube successfully, I want to get the embed link of the uploaded video, and put this link to another website, so that I can see the video from that website.

How can I get that link?

I use code below to upload the video, but I can not see any useful information from the returned ticket.

```
GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
ticket = [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:entry
                                  forFeedURL:url
                                    delegate:self 
                           didFinishSelector:@selector(uploadTicket:finishedWithEntry:error];
```

Is there anyone can help me out here?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to get the url from the entry object in your callback handler.

```
- (void)uploadTicket:(GDataServiceTicket *)ticket
   finishedWithEntry:(GDataEntryYouTubeVideo *)videoEntry
               error:(NSError *)error {
  if (error == nil) {
    NSString *url = [[[[video mediaGroup] mediaContents] objectAtIndex:0] URLString];
  }
}
```